# Delete all i386 packages from my local repository?

Tags: repository, localrepository

I just copied a repository of the previous Ubuntu version (13, saucy). It contains both i386 and amd64 versions of the packages. I want to use this repository on a 64 bit PC. Is there a terminal command I can use to remove all of the i386 versions?

Edit: I am assuming that all packages have a amd64 version. Otherwise, if a package only has an i386 version, I want to retain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A two-stage method would be to create a script which, given a path to a package, checks for the existence of an `amd64` version and if it finds such a version, deletes the `i386` package.

Something like:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

for i
do
    PKG=${i/i386/amd64}
    if [[ -f $PKG ]]
    then
        rm $1
    fi
done
```

saved as `script.sh`, for example.
And then:

```
find ${REPOSITORY_ROOT} -iname '*i386.deb' -exec ./script.sh {} +
```

The whole thing can perhaps be done using a single `find` command, but this should be enough.